# Mixing mozzarella without clumping

Tags: cheese, pasta

Whenever I use mozarella in a pasta dish, and attempt to mix it in like you would cheddar or anything else, I end up with one giant clump of mozzarella. 
Ex) I cook some pasta, and add the cheese/milk right after draining and attempt to mix.

Is there a way to thoroughly mix this hardheaded cheese?

Comment: Are we speaking of [fresh mozzarella](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Mozzarella.jpg/800px-Mozzarella.jpg) or of the [hard stuff](http://pierogiesplus.com/old/index.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=28&zenid=mq96u8ouk85choc7cesq5j7594) that is sold as such?

Comment: I'm just using store-bought shredded, like the latter picture "hard stuff"

Comment: OK, because the fresh one does not really melt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add in your cheese in small quantities and stir after each addition.

I'm not sure what you're making, but you could make a cream sauce prior to mixing the pasta with milk/cream, cheese and butter.  Again, though, you'll want to add the cheese in small quantities and ensure that it's incorporated before adding another batch.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll try that. As far as the cream sauce, how would you advise making that to avoid the same problem? Just put a pinch in, let it melt, and repeat? Or is there a method to the madness?

Comment: Yeah, you'd basically be making something like a Mornay or an Alfredo sauce.  Melt the butter, incorporate the milk/cream and, once hot, sprinkle the cheese in smaller than 1/4 cup increments stirring constantly.  Once all the cheese is in and melted, you can then incorporate your pasta.

Answer (score 2):

Your cheese is clumping like oil and water.

Okay, it is perhaps oversimplifying slightly, but this is the basic issue--your cheese is made  of, essentially, fat and protein (assuming you're using low-moisture mozzarella). The fat and water repel each other, meaning breaking up that ball of cheese is like trying to mix oil throughout a pot of water--it's going to tend to clump together.

What you need is an emulsifier, an agent that will act as a liaison between the cheese and the water to turn it into one smooth mixture. When making sauces, your go-to emulsifier is starch. This is actually quite handy because when you're making pasta you have starch in abundance! When you're done boiling your pasta, just take a bit of the water and add it to your cheese and pasta. With a little mechanical action, you'll see it all turn smooth and even before your eyes.

As far as how much to add--well that depends on how much pasta, how much cheese, how starchy your water is, etc. What I often do is drain my pasta over a bowl, add a ladle-full of water back to my cheesy sauce with the pasta, and stir for a few seconds. It will quickly become clear whether it is mixing well or whether I'll need more water.

Answer (score 0):

3 table spoon of butter
Melt in sauce pan
3 table spoons of flour
Add to melted butter
Slowly add 2 and half cups of milk GRADUALLY until mixture is right thickness for u 
Add your cheese and stir with mixture
Hope this alternative method is useful